# Issue in Converting SQL Join Query to Linq/Lambda Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am facing an issue of converting the below sql query to linq query in C#

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [KSP].[Module] AS m
     LEFT JOIN [KSP].ModuleRoleMapping] AS mrm
ON M.id = mrm.moduleid AND mrm.RoleId=1
```

"mrm.RoleId=1" --> 1 will be considering as a parameter which we are getting it from api so here instead of 1, input parameter will be passed

```cs
var result = await (
    from m in _kspContext.Modules
    join mrm in _kspContext.ModuleRoleMappings
        on new { m.Id, RoleId } equals new { mrm.ModuleId, mrm.RoleId } into moduleRoleMapping
    from subModuleRoleMapping in moduleRoleMapping.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where m.Active 
    select new ModuleRoleMappingDto() {
        ModuleId = m.Id,
        ModuleName = m.ModuleName,
        ModuleRoleMappingsId = subModuleRoleMapping.Id,
        RoleId = subModuleRoleMapping.RoleId,
        Add = subModuleRoleMapping.Add,
        Active = subModuleRoleMapping.Active,
        Delete = subModuleRoleMapping.Delete,
        Edit = subModuleRoleMapping.Edit,
        EntryOnly = subModuleRoleMapping.EntryOnly,
        Publish = subModuleRoleMapping.Publish,
        View = subModuleRoleMapping.View,
    }).ToListAsync();
```

It is incorrect statement. It is giving an error like below

The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to `GroupJoin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query which gives the result what the question wants

```
var result = await (from m in _kspContext.Modules
                            join mrm in _kspContext.ModuleRoleMappings.Where(x => x.RoleId == RoleId)
                            on  m.Id equals mrm.ModuleId into moduleRoleMapping
                            from subModuleRoleMapping in moduleRoleMapping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where m.Active 
                            select new ModuleRoleMappingDto() {
                                ModuleId = m.Id,
                                ModuleName = m.ModuleName,
                                ModuleRoleMappingId = subModuleRoleMapping.Id,
                                RoleId = subModuleRoleMapping.RoleId,
                                Add = subModuleRoleMapping.Add,
                                Active = subModuleRoleMapping.Active,
                                Delete = subModuleRoleMapping.Delete,
                                Edit = subModuleRoleMapping.Edit,
                                EntryOnly = subModuleRoleMapping.EntryOnly,
                                Publish = subModuleRoleMapping.Publish,
                                View = subModuleRoleMapping.View,
                            }).ToListAsync();
```

Finally I got the answer myself which works for me

Comment: Your query has superfluous part `join`. I have made answer which should work without that.

Answer (score 0):

var data = DBContext.Module.SelectMany(j => j.ModuleRoleMapping.Where(p=>p.RoleId = 1).DefaultIfEmpty());

Comment: if you have relation in your tables

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `SelectMany`, as described in [Complex Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause)

```cs
var query = 
    from m in _kspContext.Modules
    from subModuleRoleMapping in _kspContext.ModuleRoleMappings
        .Where(mrm => m.Id == mrm.ModuleId && mrm.RoleId == RoleId)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    where m.Active 
    select new ModuleRoleMappingDto() 
    {
        ModuleId = m.Id,
        ModuleName = m.ModuleName,
        ModuleRoleMappingId = subModuleRoleMapping.Id,
        RoleId = subModuleRoleMapping.RoleId,
        Add = subModuleRoleMapping.Add,
        Active = subModuleRoleMapping.Active,
        Delete = subModuleRoleMapping.Delete,
        Edit = subModuleRoleMapping.Edit,
        EntryOnly = subModuleRoleMapping.EntryOnly,
        Publish = subModuleRoleMapping.Publish,
        View = subModuleRoleMapping.View,
    };
```